# Best replacement for Logitech K740

Tags: keyboards, logitech

I've been using the Logitech K740 Illuminated Keyboard for years - I really love the key action on these keyboards - but now some of the keys on my current one are getting a little flakey and I wanted to buy another K740, but I can't find any. They seem to be discontinued. Does anyone know another full sized keyboard that has a similar key action?

Answer (score 0):

The Logitech K800 looks very similar, but wireless, and seems easier to find nowadays.

In my country, I can find both the K740 and the K800, although the K740 seems harder to find. In new condition, both are quite expensive. However, there are several second hand K800 on the market.

I see you're in the UK. Do specifically need a UK layout ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are referring to the `Perfectstroke Key` system, then there are other keyboards on the market such as K780 wireless keyboard.

It is missing the palm pad, but you can easily get mats with a palm pad.  And the keyboard sits on top.  I use on.  You can also get just the palm pad, such as

[image]